# How to get python default exception message in exception handling

Tags: python, exception

When I handle an exception in python

```
try:
    a = dict()
    a[1]
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

It prints

```
1
```

I expect it to print

```
KeyError: 1
```

Is there a way to retrieve the default error message ?

Comment: This code doesn't `return` anything, only prints, and second, no exception is raised...

Comment: Best to not catch generic Exceptions and expect good things to happen. The point of exceptions is that they give you a specific issue to deal with - catching the base case means you don't know what you're handling, so how can you handle it correctly?

Comment: Most of the times, I can't catch all errors and exceptions, so if I want to exit the program gracefully I need to catch generic Exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
print str(e)
```

do this:

```
print(type(e).__name__ + ": " + str(e))
```

or just this:

```
print(type(e).__name__, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `str(e)` with `repr(e)` Python 2 will produce `KeyError(1,)` and Python 3 will produce `KeyError(1)`

This doesn't quite produce your desired output, but it may be close enough?